# start Zynaddsubfx with no GUI in the PI

Tags: audio

I need to run jackd and zynaddsubfx in a headless PI.
I have an external USB audio card that works (I can play stuff with aplay blablabla.wav)

I can run jack1 with no GUI nicelly and connect stuff using aconnect. But **I cannot start Zynaddsubfx with no GUI** I use the -U param that is meant for that. But it says: "cannot open device".
In the other hand if I use Xming to forward X11 and I don't use the -U, Zynaddsubfx opens in my windows machine (via Xming) and everything works nicelly. (same happens if I plug the raspi to a TV and startx before starting everything).

They told me that there is a version 2.4.3, but I cannot get it from apt-get, I updated and even dist-upgraded. Nothing new for me. This is what I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ apt-cache policy zynaddsubfx
zynaddsubfx:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2.4.0-2
Version table:
2.4.0-2 0
500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
```

And just to see that the sound card is there:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 151
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 136 [90%] [-2.88dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 134 [89%] [-3.25dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined cvolume cvolume-joined
                pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127 Capture 0 - 16
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [0.00dB] [off] Capture 0 [0%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto Gain Control',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

Comment: I fixed half of the issue. I addedthe answer to this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of fixed it by using Jack1. it's better to use itwhen you want to go headless. due to the dbus dependency of Jack2. and anyway, you cannot enjoy Jack2 really nice in a single core device.
 the problem with zynaddsubfx is still there.